# Preserve color running an external command via exec

Tags: perl, colors, terminal, exec

Is it possible to run an external command in a perl script and preserve the color?

As a simple example, how would I run `ls` from a perl script and get colored output:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

exec "ls";
```

When I run this, the output is all white, but I would like to preserve the colors, in this example for the directories and executables, etc...

Comment: Do you mean `eval` or `exec`?

Comment: My mistake, I meant `exec`

Comment: Programming is all about attention to detail :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that `ls` doesn't automatically turn on colours in a subshell.

```
$ echo `ls`
# Output is uncoloured
```

We can work around that by using the `--color` command-line option.

```
$ echo `ls --color`
# Output is coloured
```

You can use a similar trick in a subshell that is invoked from Perl.

```
$ perl -e 'system "ls"'
# Output is uncoloured

$ perl -e 'system "ls --color"'
# Output is coloured.
```

Comment: Thank you! I should have tried `exec` with something different than `ls` before posting it here.

Comment: `ls` doesn't automatically turn on colors in the regular shell either. But `ls` is often (by default in Ubuntu, for example) aliased to `ls --color=auto`.

Comment: @mob: Thanks. I was trying to work out exactly what had happened there.